# No CentOS in maas 2.2 or 2.3 image selection

Tags: maas

Today I installed maas 2.2.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.1.
Under the "Ubuntu: Select images and architecture to be imported and kept in sync daily" section, no CentOS images are listed in either the maas.io tab or in Custom with http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily

Then I ran `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maas/next` and upgraded to 2.3.0 and still no CentOS.

How do I add CentOS to maas? All the answers I've found so far are 2 years old and didn't solve the issue. I appreciate any help on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I manually downloaded centos7 from  [here](http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily) and was able to create boot resource from that image.

```
maas $yourProfile boot-resources create name=centos/centos7 architecture=amd64/generic content@=downloaded-image-file
```